# Хочу понять значение предложения, а то возникают сомнения

Tags: лексика

Недавно написал своей знакомой такое: ваши слова не менее ценны, чем вы сами.
Это же можно считать за комплимент? Или такое предложение звучит странно?

Comment: Грамматика нормальная, но вот комплимент ли это? Нужен контекст, а то по-разному можно понять...   Выражение  чувств, речевой штамп и т.д.  В таких случаях каждое слово нужно выбирать)  Можно, к примеру, написать так: Мне дороги ваши слова, как и вы сами. Это предложение более простое и искреннее.

Comment: Немного странное, но наверное, ваш друг хотел сказать, что ваши слова и вы для него ценны. Хотя употребление не менее, чем выглядит не совсем уместно. Но может быть, что такая неоднозначная конструкция была использована специально. Обычно говорят наоборот, вы для нас не менее ценны, чем ваша работа. А тут получается, что часть вас не менее ценна, чем вы целый - парадокс. А не менее ценно, чем А+Б - получается, что Б = 0. Забавно звучит.